# weakly continuous vs weakly sequentially continuous operator

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Im reading some papers where the condition of weak sequential continuity is crucial, and this question come to my mind:

Why it's more interesting to use this condition instead of the classical weak continuity?

**Context:**

- $T$ between a Banach space X and itself.
- $T$ is weakly sequentially continuous if for any $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, $x_n \stackrel{w}{\rightharpoonup}x$ in $X$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(x_n) \stackrel{w}{\rightharpoonup } T( x )$ in $X$).

Comment: All of these conditions boil down to norm continuity of $T$.  But of course some might be easier to verify in concrete situations.

Comment: Can you give more explication, I  will appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

**Theorem**. Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed vector spaces and let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear map.  Then the following are equivalent:

1. $T$ is continuous,
2. $T$ is weakly continuous,
3. $T$ is sequentially weakly continuous,
4. For every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in {\bf N}}$ in $X$ which is weakly convergent  to $0$, one can find a weakly converging subsequence $\{T(x_{n_k})\}_{k\in {\bf N}}$.

*Proof*. The implications (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2) $\Rightarrow$ (3) $\Rightarrow$ (4) are trivial, so let us prove that (4)
$\Rightarrow$ (1).  Arguing by contradiction assume that $T$ is not continuous, hence unbounded on the unit ball of
$X$.  So we can find a sequence $\{y_n\}_{n\in {\bf N}}$ in that ball such that $\Vert T(y_n)\Vert >n^2$,  for every $n$.  Setting
$x_n=y_n/n$, we have that $x_n\to 0$ in norm, so also weakly, while
$$
  \Vert T(x_n)\Vert = {1\over n}  \Vert T(y_n)\Vert  > {1\over n}n^2 = n,
  $$
so no subsequence of $\{T(x_n)\}_{n\in {\bf N}}$ is  weakly convergent because weakly convergent sequences are
bounded (by a well known Corollary of the uniform boundedness principle).  This contradicts (4), so the proof is complete. QED

Comment: Unfortunately, $T$ is not supposed to be linear, but thanks for your answer anyway..

Comment: Oh!  I am sorry.  But since the majority of facts about functions between Banach spaces involve linear maps, it is perhaps wise to emphasize it when you are considering non-linear maps!